# Building a numpy array (matrix) from several dataframes

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have several dataframes which have the same look but different data.

**DataFrame 1**

```
                          bid
                        close
time                         
2016-05-24 00:00:00       NaN
2016-05-24 00:05:00  0.000611
2016-05-24 00:10:00 -0.000244
2016-05-24 00:15:00 -0.000122
```

**DataFrame 2**

```
                          bid
                        close
time                         
2016-05-24 00:00:00       NaN
2016-05-24 00:05:00  0.000811
2016-05-24 00:10:00 -0.000744
2016-05-24 00:15:00 -0.000322
```

I need to build a list of the dataframes, then pass that list of dataframes to a function that can take a list of dataframes and converts it to a numpy array. So below, each entry in the matrix is the elements of the dataframe ('bid
                        close') column. Notice I don't need the index 'time' column

```
data = np.array([dataFrames])
```

returns this (example not actual data)

```
[[-0.00114415  0.02502565  0.00507831 ...,  0.00653057  0.02183072
  -0.00194293] `DataFrame` 1 is here ignore that the data doesn't match above
 [-0.01527224  0.02899528 -0.00327654 ...,  0.0322364   0.01821731
  -0.00766773] `DataFrame` 2 is here ignore that the data doesn't match above
 ....]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
master_matrix = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis=1)
master_matrix = master_matrix.values.reshape(master_matrix.shape, order='F')
```

if each row in the final matrix corresponds to the same date

```
master_matrix = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis=1).values
```

otherwise.

Edit to address the newly added example.
In this case, you can use `np.vstack` on columns returned from each dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''
time                bid_close
2016-05-24 00:00:00       NaN
2016-05-24 00:05:00  0.000611
2016-05-24 00:10:00 -0.000244
2016-05-24 00:15:00 -0.000122
'''), sep=r' +')

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''
time                bid_close
2016-05-24 00:00:00       NaN
2016-05-24 00:05:00  0.000811
2016-05-24 00:10:00 -0.000744
2016-05-24 00:15:00 -0.000322
'''), sep=r' +')

dfs = [df1, df2]

out = np.vstack(df.iloc[:,-1].values for df in dfs)
```

Result:

```
In [10]: q.out
Out[10]:
array([[      nan,  0.000611, -0.000244, -0.000122],
       [      nan,  0.000811, -0.000744, -0.000322]])
```

Comment: that returns a numpy array?

Comment: bad naming; fixed. in general, `df.values` returns a numpy array.

Comment: That is pretty cool and close, but not quite what I need. This is the result [  6.11097531e-04  -7.07217396e-05  -9.88878916e-05  -6.22477917e-05
   -1.05367416e-05] I need the entire dataframe across in each row. So it is as wide as  there are data in the dataframes, and tall as there are dataframes.

Comment: Can you provide one additional input, and the desired result for the case with 2 inputs?

Comment: I clarified the original post. The entire bid column of dataframe 1 becomes a row in the numpy array[0]. The entire bid column of dataframe 2 becomes a row in numpy array[1] and so on...

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4],
                   index=pd.date_range('2016-04-01', periods=4),
                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bid', 'close')]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([5, 6, 7, 8],
                   index=pd.date_range('2016-03-01', periods=4),
                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bid', 'close')]))
print df1

             bid
           close
2016-04-01     1
2016-04-02     2
2016-04-03     3
2016-04-04     4

print df2

             bid
           close
2016-03-01     5
2016-03-02     6
2016-03-03     7
2016-03-04     8
```

#### Solution

```
df = np.concatenate([d.T.values for d in [df1, df2]])

print df

[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

---

#### Note

The indices were not required to line up.  This just takes the raw `np.array` from each dataframe and uses `np.concatenate` to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure which to use above or this.